# Where to enter non-form data in postman?

Tags: postman

I have newbie question about how to submit a non form data for `GET` request in postman `7.0.6`. Since it is not a form data, I choose tab `params` and enter `_device_id` as key and `deviceid` as value. But I have `req.body._device_id` on server end as `undefined`.

Then I enter the key and value under `body -> form data` and the result is the same. It is `undefined` for `req.body._device_id`. Both form or non form failed submitting the key/value.

Where to enter and submit a non-form key/value in postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add any parameter under Params tab, it passes into URL, not in *body*. So, your request URL would look like.

```
https://foo.com?_device_id=deviceid
```

Now on the other hand while on the server side you're trying to access the data from the body instead of URL with `req.body._device_id`. This will *never true* as your request type is GET, it shouldn't contain a body.

Therefore, you need to get your param value from URL by using `req.query._device_id`